# How do I use "series"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

All of the examples I found either used the word with an article (*That's the series you talked about?*) or with an adjective (*a comedy series, TV series*).

1. Can I say "What series do you watch?" instead of "What *TV series* do you watch?"
2. Do English speakers usually understand TV series to be any show, not just one made for the literal television?

Comment: A _series_ is a sequence of TV or radio programmes, or books, about the same group of characters, or connected by the same theme. You can say "What series do you watch?" if it's clear from the context that you are talking about TV.

Comment: Most people will probably understand "TV series" and "TV shows" to include Netflix shows and the like, which might never have been broadcast in a traditional sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, because "TV series" means different things in different countries.

In the USA, it refers to every episode of a given show.  But in other countries, it refers to the year of a show.  Example:

USA:
"I am watching season two of the show Seinfeld."

Others:
"I am watching series two of the show Seinfeld."

Your best option in the different situations is to phrase it as, "What TV shows do you watch?"  Or in the USA you can just say, "What shows do you watch," and TV will be assumed.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the piece of information I've been missing :)